# Access a Movie Clip in a Movie Clip - actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a game in ActionScript 3 and I've ran in to a problem.

I have a UI in the game that is in one Movie Clip. Inside the UI-Movie Clip there are several other Movie Clips, like a HP bar.

I add the UI-Movie Clip to the game like this:

> var ui:ui_mc = new ui_mc();
>
> addChild(ui_mc);

Now I want to access and change frames, and so on, on the HP bar-Movie Clip in an update-function, but I don't know how to.

Any ideas? Or is this just a bad way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, solved it..

For you who don't know: You have to give the Movie Clips in your parent Movie Clips instance names.

Comment: Tutorial on instance names [here](http://www.trainingtutorials101.com/2011/05/as3-instance-names-as3-movie-clip.html)